# Liquibase migrations not running on different environment

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, kotlin, liquibase

I'm having issues where liquibase change scripts are running in the uat environment, but are not running in the production environment, with the same configurations. When running in the production environment, the following happens:

```
    2018-11-05 14:51:11.269  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2018-11-05 14:51:11.285  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2018-11-05 14:51:11.293  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT LOCKED FROM MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1 FOR UPDATE
2018-11-05 14:51:11.336  INFO 1 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully acquired change log lock
2018-11-05 14:51:11.538  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT MD5SUM FROM MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL AND ROWNUM=1
2018-11-05 14:51:11.541  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOG
2018-11-05 14:51:11.548  INFO 1 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Reading from MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOG
2018-11-05 14:51:11.548  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2018-11-05 14:51:11.566 INFO 1 --- [ main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService : Successfully released change log lock
```

Yet, at the end of the migration, the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table is empty and the structural changes on the database haven't been effected. The database is an Oracle database on both environments.

Does anyone know what I should look out for?

Comment: provide more details about how are you running your migrations

Answer (score 0):

You should have missed the change log file on your command line or from your configuration tool used to launch liquibase.

In your log, there isn't any error, but no change where needed.